# jQuery Multiple If Else statement

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to write the following code. My code finds a geographical location of the user and to handle errors I have used multiple if else statements

```
<script> 
 $(function () { 
     var error = $('#errDiv'); 
     $('#btnFindLoc').click(function () { 
         if (Modernizr.geolocation) { 
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(currentPosition, positionError); 
         } 
         else { 
             error.html("GeoLocation API of HTML 5 is not supported"); 
         } 
     }); 

     function currentPosition(currentPos) { 
         var coordinates = currentPos.coords; 
         $('#lati').text(coordinates.latitude); 
         $('#longi').text(coordinates.longitude);
        var googleMap = $('#gMap'); 
         googleMap.attr("href", "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + coordinates.latitude + "," + coordinates.longitude); 
     } 

     function positionError(errCode) { 
         if (errCode.code==0) { 
             error.html("Unknown Error - has occured"); 
         } 
         else if (errCode.code==1) { 
             error.html("Permission Denied - By the user"); 
         } 
         else if (errCode.code==2) { 
             error.html("Position/Location Unavailable"); 
         } 
         else if (errCode.code == 3) { 
             error.html("Timeout"); 
         } 
     } 
 }); 
 </script>
```

Is there a better way to write this entire code or is this code ok?

Comment: use switch statements.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You can write this functionality in multiple ways, and all of them would be "ok" if they give you the correct result.

Comment: .. but there is no real problem with using `if else` statements

Comment: Questions regarding improving working code are a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other alternative is the switch statement. Even though, I am not sure it it makes such a difference. For your code, it would like like this:

```
switch (errCode.code) {
    case 0:
        error.html("Unknown Error - has occured"); 
        break;
    case 1:
        error.html("Permission Denied - By the user"); 
        break;
    case 2:
        error.html("Position/Location Unavailable"); 
        break;
    case 3:
        error.html("Timeout"); 
        break;
    }
```

The switch also allows you to specify a default option. Another thing you can do is treat two cases the same way.

```
switch (errCode.code) {
    case 0:
        error.html("Unknown Error - has occured"); 
        break;
    case 1:
        error.html("Permission Denied - By the user"); 
        break;
    case 2:
        error.html("Position/Location Unavailable"); 
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
        error.html("Timeout"); 
        break;
    default: 
        error.html("Some other error");
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `switch` statements:

```
function positionError(errCode) { 
     switch(errCode.code) {
         case 0:
             error.html("Unknown Error - has occured"); 
         break;

         case 1: 
             error.html("Permission Denied - By the user"); 
         break;

         case 2: 
             error.html("Position/Location Unavailable"); 
         break;

         case 3:
             error.html("Timeout");
         break;

         default:
             error.html("Unknown Error"); 
         break;
     }
 }
```

(I've added a `default` case to handle unknown error codes)